# SageMaker - cannot import sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to import sklearn in SageMaker Notebook but unable to do so, getting the below error.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sagemaker.sklearn'

Is there any other SageMaker extension to be installed ?

**SageMaker Code - Studio**
[image]

**Kernel**
[image]

Comment: Can you add the version you are using of sagemaker (in your notebook run `!pip freeze | grep sagemaker`) and the code you are using to import the library?

Comment: import sagemaker
from sagemaker.sklearn import SKLearn                                                                    
                                                                                                                                    
!pip freeze | grep sagemaker                                                           
sagemaker==2.116.0
sagemaker-experiments==0.1.39
sagemaker-scikit-learn-extension==2.5.0
sagemaker-studio-analytics-extension==0.0.10
sagemaker-studio-sparkmagic-lib==0.1.4

Comment: Which kernel are you using? Looks like Sparkmagic kernel

Comment: I have updated Kernel details (Python3) and Issue code base.

Comment: Seems to be an environment error. Can you try using image `Data Science 3.0`?

Comment: Thanks for the info. This issue got resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the compromised image/environment.

I recommend directly using the most up-to-date image that includes python 3.10:

`Data Science 3.0`